# SSIS migration from 2005 to 2008? Just opening in BIDS 2008 (which will do conversions) and then deploying in 2008 enviorment work?

Tags: ssis, vsta, ssis-2005

I have been given a task to migrate 2005 packages to  2008, I was looking for discontinued features by SSIS 2008 on http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb500429(v=sql.100).aspx 
It seems VSA is discontinued and replace by VSTA. As I am doing such work first time I just wanted to check opening packages BIDS 2008 and then deploying them in 2008 enviorment will do or I will need to some other stuff also?

Comment: You can open your SSIS 2005 package in VS 2008 .It will ask you to upgrade the  package.Once done you can easily deploy it in 2008 environment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me, the VSA -> VSTA change you just mentioned simply means that now we can code in C# :D

Overall, to migrate you just need to opne the package on BIDS 2008, but there are a few things you need to take care yourself. What it comes to my mind for example is the behavior of lookup tasks have changed a little  (the way no match rows are treated) and the order variables are loaded from config files changed too. I mean, just by running and debugig your pakcages you should be able to test these kind of things

Comment: Thanks @Diego while upgrading through BIDS I have encounter below warning  "Warning at  [Package Format Migration Module]: The Maximum insert commit size property of the OLE DB destination "" is set to 0. This property setting can cause the running package to stop responding."  What should be rememdy of this?

Comment: A value of 0 might cause the running package to stop responding if the OLE DB destination and another data flow component are updating the same source table. To prevent the package from stopping, set the Maximum insert commit size option to 2147483647.

This is not new, though. It is around since SSIS 2005. Maybe its a warning due to the migration.

Answer (score 0):

The migration is done very well by just opening the package, even the code change.

A couple gotchas are:
1. If you have ConnectionString in your config, you have to change Provider from SQLNCLI.1 to
`Provider=SQLNCLI10.1;`  (or add the old provider to your new SSIS 2008 production server.
2.  I have a case where a space gets in there and gives me an error.  I fix in Connection connectionString property by removing the space.  It is hard to see in BIDS.  `Provider= SQLNCLI10.1;`